# What is the correct way to include a blank line in an html list element?

Tags: html, css

Assuming I have a list:

- Item One
- Item Two is really long. As a matter of fact, it's made up of a couple different paragraphs. I'd really like to be able to have a break between the second and third sentence because otherwise it gets all bunched together and is really difficult to read.
- Item Three

What is the correct way to achieve this in HTML/CSS:

- Item One
- Item Two is really long. As a matter of fact, it's made up of a couple different paragraphs.

  I'd really like to be able to have a break between the second and third sentence because otherwise it gets all bunched together and is really difficult to read.
- Item Three

It seems some options are `<p>`, `<div>`, and perhaps `<span>` with the appropriate `display` style. There are probably even more options, but I am hoping there is a correct / recommended approach.

For the sake of scoping this question, let's assume modern browsers that support HTML5/CSS3.

*Edit: For people voting to close the question, could you leave a comment as to why? If there's some obvious guideline I should follow, please link to it. Given that there are often multiple ways to accomplish things in HTML/CSS, I think it's fair to ask if there is a "correct" way.*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`<p>` stands for paragraph, so this would be the recommended way, but, all the other ways are valid as well.

Comment: So many ways to accomplish one thing .... I was unsure if perhaps <p> insides <li> might be a bad idea (not sure why).

Answer (score 12):

`<span>` is not recommended as it's not a block element.

You can use `<br>` to breakline:

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    Item One
  </li>

  <li>
    Item Two is really long. As a matter of fact, it's made up of a couple different paragraphs.
    <br><br>I'd really like to be able to have a break between the second and third sentence because otherwise it gets all bunched together and is really difficult to read.
  </li>
  <li>
    Item Three
  </li>
</ul>
```

You can as well us an empty `block` element and set a size to it using CSS:

```css
.spacer {
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
Item Two is really long. As a matter of fact, it's made up of a couple different paragraphs.
<div class="spacer"></div>I'd really like to be able to have a break between the second and third sentence because otherwise it gets all bunched together and is really difficult to read.
```

Or a `<p>` tag:

```html
    <p>Item Two is really long. As a matter of fact, it's made up of a couple different paragraphs.</p>
    <p>I'd really like to be able to have a break between the second and third sentence because otherwise it gets all bunched together and is really difficult to read.</p>
```

Comment: I appreciate the comment as to why <span> is not a good idea. That's the type of answer I was looking for, and furthermore, hoping there was _a_ good idea. Perhaps, it seems, there are many usable ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add, that putting a `<br>` or `<p>` outside the `<li>` but inside the parent `<ul>` throws an error when checking this with html validators.

**So this is accepted:**

```
<ul>
    <li>
       .....
    <br>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**and this not.**

```
<ul>
    <li>
       .....
    </li>
    <br>
</ul>
```

This might be clear or logical to many, but I had to learn this today, especially as this thread encouraged me that 
 is the correct method (=element), but that merely my placement was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I use a `<hr>` because is the semantic tag to represent that kind of break.

For historical reason the element is displayed as a horizontal line, so you need a bit of CSS to change the visual.

```
<ul>
  <li>
    Item One
  </li>

  <li>
    Item Two is really long. As a matter of fact, it's made up of a couple different paragraphs.
    <hr style="border: none;">I'd really like to be able to have a break between the second and third sentence because otherwise it gets all bunched together and is really difficult to read.
  </li>
  <li>
    Item Three
  </li>
</ul>
```